# Firma digital de un PDF con C Sharp e itext

Tags: c#, firma-digital, itextsharp

En mi trabajo utilizan firma digital para validar archivos PDF que después son entregados a los que los solicitan (quienes no pertenecen a la empresa), por lo que en el PDF debe verse la firma con los datos del firmante.

La firma se está realizando con el asistente de Adobe y utilizando tokens con firma digital instalados en el equipo.

Las personas que tienen que firmar firman cerca de 200 PDF por día, por lo que estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio en C# que me permita firmar todos los PDF de una sola vez, ya que con Adobe tienen que abrir el PDF, crear un campo de firma, poner la clave del token y recién aparece la firma, esto multiplicado por 100 ó 200 según el dia. Por lo que estuve investigando, se puede hacer.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es un botón que abre un dialog que te permite seleccionar todos los PDF a firmar. Después otro botón que abre el almacén de certificados de Windows para seleccionar el certifcado para firmar. Pero no consigo crear un campo e insertar la firma, pidiendo previamente la clave del token.

```
////Con el método de abajo abro el almacén de certificados y selecciono uno para firmar.

private void btnExplorar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        X509Store store= new X509Store(StoreName.My,StoreLocation.CurrentUser);


        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

        X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Lista de Certificados digitales instalados en su equipo", "Seleccion el certificado con el que desea firmar", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
        //  X509Certificate2 certificadoElegido = scollection[0];

        if (scollection.Count > 0)
        {

          certificadoElegido = scollection[0];//certificadoElegido es vble de clase

    }

//Con este método recorro un listbox con la lista de todos los PDF seleccionados para firmar e intento crear un campo, pero no sé como lograr que ese campo se cree en el PDF y hacer la firma. Necesito por supuesto que esa firma se vea luego en el PDF para que los solicitantes sepan quién se los firmó.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cLBoxListadePdf.CheckedItems.Count!=0) {
            string pdfAFirmar;
            int i;
            for (i=0;i<=cLBoxListadePdf.CheckedItems.Count-1;i++) {
                pdfAFirmar = cLBoxListadePdf.CheckedItems[i].ToString();

                PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(pdfAFirmar);
                PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdf,new FileStream("C:\\Users\...", FileMode.Create), '\0');
                PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                sap.Reason = "";
                //sap.Location=100;
                stamper.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Cualquier sugerencia de cómo completar este trabajo es bienvenida.

Answer (score 4):

El código que uso para firmar PDF con itextsharp es el siguiente, espero que te sirva.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.security;

using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

using SysX509 = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


namespace FirmaPDF
{
    public class firma
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Firma un documento PDF
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Source">Path del PDF a firmar</param>
        /// <param name="Target">Path del PDF firmado</param>
        /// <param name="Certificate">Certificado para realizar la firma</param>
        /// <param name="Reason">Motivo</param>
        /// <param name="Location">Ubicación</param>
        /// <param name="AddVisibleSign">Indica si la firma es visible dentro del documento</param>
        /// <param name="AddTimeStamp">Indica si se va a añadir sello de tiempo en el documento</param>
        /// <param name="strTSA">TSA del sello de tiempo</param>

        public static void SignHashed(string Source, string Target, SysX509.X509Certificate2 Certificate, string Reason, string Location, bool AddVisibleSign, bool AddTimeStamp, string strTSA)
        {
            X509CertificateParser objCP = new X509CertificateParser();
            X509Certificate[] objChain = new X509Certificate[] { objCP.ReadCertificate(Certificate.RawData) };

            IList<ICrlClient> crlList = new List<ICrlClient>();
            crlList.Add(new CrlClientOnline(objChain));

            PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader(Source);
            PdfStamper objStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(objReader, new FileStream(Target, FileMode.Create), '\0',null,true);

            // Creamos la apariencia
            PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = objStamper.SignatureAppearance;
            signatureAppearance.Reason = Reason;
            signatureAppearance.Location = Location;

            // Si está la firma visible:
            if (AddVisibleSign)
                signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200), 1, null); //signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), objReader.NumberOfPages, "Signature");

            ITSAClient tsaClient = null;
            IOcspClient ocspClient = null;

            // Si se ha añadido el sello de tiempo
            if (AddTimeStamp){
                ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
                tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(strTSA);
            }

            // Creating the signature
            IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(Certificate, "SHA-1");
            MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, objChain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

            if (objReader != null)
                objReader.Close();
            if (objStamper != null)
                objStamper.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Gemis. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. ¿Podrás comentar, al menos brevemente en qué consiste la solución que estás presentando? La idea del sitio es generar contenido con la mayor calidad posible. Más info en [answer].

Comment: Hola @Mariano. La solución que presento es una función que firma un PDF en c# con itextsharp (versión 5). El código lo encontré en la siguiente URL: [enlace](http://www.programandoamedianoche.com/2010/06/como-firmar-un-documento-pdf-desde-c-sharp-con-itextsharp/). Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Gemis. Voy a probar el codigo y te cuento como me fue.

Comment: gracias por la solución, sin embargo quisiera saber cómo cambiar el tamaño de fuente a la descripción de la firma, resulta que es muy grande y quisiera achicarlo. Por otro lado no logro poder desplegar el correo de contacto desde el certificado.
Quedo atento a tu respuesta.
Saludos.